Evaluation inside StrGobbleRight
I'm running into a problem with a list of IfSubStr that will be separated by commas and spaces. I don't want the final substring to have that comma and space, so I thought StrGobbleRight(2) would be the right approach. However, now I have an expanding issue. The result is an "Illegal parameter number in definition of \xs_arg_i."
I'd like to make the StrGobbleRight(2) work to trim off the trailing comma and space, or barring that, have the code only add commas and spaces between the output, not after it.
Here's the code:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz} % a lot
\usetikzlibrary{math} % maths
\usepackage{xstring} % string comparisons

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand{\makeDndNPCStats}{ m m m m m m m m }{
    
            \StrGobbleRight{
                \IfSubStr{#8}{str}{Str~+\pgfmathtruncatemacro\resultstr{(#1-10)/2+#7}\resultstr,~}{}
                \IfSubStr{#8}{dex}{Dex~+\pgfmathtruncatemacro\resultdex{(#2-10)/2+#7}\resultdex,~}{}
                \IfSubStr{#8}{con}{Con~+\pgfmathtruncatemacro\resultcon{(#3-10)/2+#7}\resultcon,~}{}
                \IfSubStr{#8}{int}{Int~+\pgfmathtruncatemacro\resultint{(#4-10)/2+#7}\resultint,~}{}
                \IfSubStr{#8}{wis}{Wis~+\pgfmathtruncatemacro\resultwis{(#5-10)/2+#7}\resultwis,~}{}
                \IfSubStr{#8}{cha}{Cha~+\pgfmathtruncatemacro\resultcha{(#6-10)/2+#7}\resultcha,~}{}
            }{2}
}

{
\makeDndNPCStats
    {11} % STR
    {12} % DEX
    {13} % CON
    {14} % INT
    {15} % WIS
    {16} % CHA
    {3} % Proficiency
    {wis,cha} % Saves
}

\end{document}

For an example input, I would write,
\makeDndNPCStats{11}{12}{13}{14}{15}{16}{3}{wis cha}

and I would expect the output,
Wis +5, Cha +6


Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ....

I've added import statements. Hope that helps.

don't just post a fragment that can't be run, post a small test document: it makes it much easier for people to answer. xstring functions are not expandable and it's usually simpler to use the expl3 functions that are built in to latex and don't need any package,  but you haven't actually said what you want this code to do, only that it generates errors.

Understood. Let me know if this is better.

It would be helpful to know, for a specified syntax of invocation, what output you are hoping to achieve.

Happy to. I've added that in.

wis (12-10)/2 + 3 = 4  (not 5)?? char = (14-10)/2 + 3 = 5 (not 6) ??

You're confusing the example input given outside and inside of the sample code. I'll edit so they're the same.

I think you want something like this, just using built in latex functions without using any external package.
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn\rs_sep:{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\makeDndNPCStats}{ m m m m m m m m }{
  \cs_set:Npn\rs_sep:{}
  \clist_map_inline:nn{#8}{
    \rs_sep:\cs_set:Npn\rs_sep:{,~}
    \str_case:nnF {##1} {
            {str}{Str~\int_eval:n{(#1-10)/2+#7}}
            {dex}{Dex~\int_eval:n{(#2-10)/2+#7}}
            {con}{Con~\int_eval:n{(#3-10)/2+#7}}
            {int}{Int~\int_eval:n{(#4-10)/2+#7}}
            {wis}{Wis~\int_eval:n{(#5-10)/2+#7}}
            {cha}{Cha~\int_eval:n{(#6-10)/2+#7}}
            }
           {2}
         }
         }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeDndNPCStats
    {17} % STR
    {10} % DEX
    {13} % CON
    {11} % INT
    {12} % WIS
    {14} % CHA
    {3} % Proficiency
    {wis,cha} % Saves

    \bigskip

    \makeDndNPCStats
    {11} % STR
    {12} % DEX
    {13} % CON
    {14} % INT
    {15} % WIS
    {16} % CHA
    {3} % Proficiency
    {wis,cha} % Saves

\end{document}


Perfect! Thank you very much.

I propose a different syntax for your command. Since it's really difficult to remember the order of the arguments and, indeed, you add the keys for a check, I believe it's better to use a “key-value” syntax. This way the values can be given in any order.
It should be noted that \int_eval:n rounds division instead of truncate, so \int_eval:n { (<value>-10)/2+#3 } would not give the expected result (like \pgfmathtruncatemacro does); hence \int_div_truncate:nn has to be used.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\makeDndNPCStats}{ m m m }
 {
  \rsed_makestats:nnn {#1} {#2} {#3}
 }

\seq_new:N \l__rsed_makestats_output_seq
\prop_new:N \l__rsed_makestats_values_prop

\cs_new_protected:Nn \rsed_makestats:nnn
 {
  \prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l__rsed_makestats_values_prop { #1 }
  \seq_clear:N \l__rsed_makestats_values_seq
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #3 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Ne \l__rsed_makestats_output_seq
     {
      \text_titlecase_first:n {##1} , \exp_not:N \nobreakspace
      \int_eval:n
       {
        \int_div_truncate:nn {\prop_item:Nn \l__rsed_makestats_values_prop {##1}-10}{2}+#2
       }
     }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l__rsed_makestats_output_seq { ,~ }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\makeDndNPCStats{
  str=11,
  dex=12,
  con=13,
  int=14,
  wis=15,
  cha=16
}{3}{wis,cha}

\makeDndNPCStats{
  dex=12,
  con=13,
  int=14,
  str=11,
  cha=16,
  wis=15,
}{3}{dex,wis,cha,str}

\end{document}



Thank you so much for the elegant alternative! I have a coding background so the key-value system appeals to me as well, but my LaTeX knowledge is subpar so I often don't know how to do it besides with brute force. I would rate your answer up but I don't have the reputation I'm afraid.
